# Why we combine two people as one?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In class we have 20 students, the probability that one student born in specific month is equal for each month in the year.
>
> What the probability that Alice and Bob born in the same month if we know that no one born in July and August and at least one student born in September.

So if no one has born in July and August then we can say that $|\Omega|=10^{20}$.
Now, we define A as an event which Alice and Bob born in the same month. and B as an event that at least one student born in September.

We need for: $Pr(A|B)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$.

$Pr(B)=\frac{10^{20}-9^{20}}{10^{20}}$

$Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{\color{red}{10^{18}-9^{18}}}{10^{20}}$

My qustions - a. Why in red is incorrect?
b. Why we need and why is it correct to look at Alice and Bob as one person?

Comment: Maybe this will help: The probability you and I are born in the same month is (under the assumption of equal days in each month) $1/12$. This is a very different question, for example, than asking the probability we are both born in January.

Comment: @DavidPeterson The probability we are both born in January is 1/12(for you) * 1/12(for me) = 1/144. but if you and I are born in the same month is 1/12 since we look at you and I as one person. correct?
If it is correct - then if we discuss on specific "something" we evaluate it for each and when is it same (under the assumption of uniform distribution) we "look" as one object. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Not one person. The month you are born in is fixed. So the question can be rephrased as what is the probability I was born in *your* month. Alternatively, you can account for every possibility, and you will have $\sum_{i=1}^{12} \left(\dfrac{1}{12}\cdot \dfrac{1}{12}\right) = \dfrac{1}{12}$